# Using Umbraco search with tags

Tags: xslt, search, umbraco, umbraco-tags

I have setup umbraco search xslt package. In my xslt I am searching by pagename, title, description and now, tags.

The tags property is a document type property of the type, 'Tags'. The search xslt is below;

```
<xsl:variable name="searchFields" select="ps:getListParameter(string(//macro/searchFields), '@pageName, title, description, tags')"/>
```

How come searching by tags doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say the document has a property of type "Tags" but you have listed the parameters as "tags". Remember that XSLT is case sensitive.

Also, I don't have Umbraco open in front of me but does the XSLT search not reference the property "alias" rather than the property type?

Answer (score 1):

XSLTSearch will split the searchfield by the comma, but it does not trim the aliases after that, so you are searching in the " tags" field (not the extra first space). If you remove the spaces, you should be fine.